# How can I print Winforms DataGrid to paper?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How can I print a System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid to paper?
I'm using .NET 3.5 framwork in C#

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example using the [`System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.printpage.aspx) class (not complete, but shows how to wire everything together):

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
    DataGrid dataGrid1 = new DataGrid();
    Button printGrid = new Button();
    PrintDocument printDocument1 = new PrintDocument();

    public MyForm()
    {
        printGrid.Click += new EventHandler(printGrid_Click);
        printDocument1.PrintPage +=
            new PrintPageEventHandler(printDocument1_PrintPage);
    }

    private void printGrid_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        printDocument1.Print();
    }

    private void printDocument1_PrintPage(System.Object sender, 
        System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        PaintEventArgs myPaintArgs = 
            new PaintEventArgs(e.Graphics, 
                               new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), this.Size));
        this.InvokePaint(dataGrid1, myPaintArgs);
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me, prints something that vaguely resembles a datagrid without headers or data.